# HLA: why is EAX register holding zero value upon exiting a recursive procedure?

Tags: stored-procedures, recursion, hla

I am trying to use a recursive procedure to compute A-B in high-level assembly. After computing the difference, it is stored in the EAX register for display at the end of the program.

**My problem:** The values in registers EAX and EBX are correct before exiting the procedure, but I do not understand why EAX is always zero when A is greater than B.

Is there something about the ret() command that is causing this? What is wrong with my code? Someone please help me.

Here is the sample code:

```
program MainSubtractionFunction;
#include( "stdlib.hhf" );
static
    iDataValue1 : int32 := 0;
    iDataValue2 : int32 := 0;
    DifferenceInt : int32 :=69;
procedure recursiveSubtraction( a: int32; b : int32 ); @nodisplay; @noframe;
static
    returnAddress : dword;
    value: int32;
begin recursiveSubtraction;
    pop( returnAddress );
    pop( b );           
    pop( a );
    push( returnAddress );
    mov (a, EAX);
    mov (b, EBX);
    CompareB:
    cmp (EBX, 0);
    je ExitSequence;
    CompareA:
    cmp (EAX, 0);
    je AEqualsZero;
    NeitherEqualZero:
    sub (1, EAX);
    sub (1, EBX);
    push(EAX);
    push(EBX);
    call recursiveSubtraction;
    AEqualsZero:
        neg (EBX);
        mov (EBX, EAX);
        jmp ExitSequence;
    BEqualsZero:
        jmp ExitSequence;
    ExitSequence:
        ret();
    end recursiveSubtraction;
begin MainSubtractionFunction;
    stdout.put( "Feed Me A: " );
    stdin.get( iDataValue1 );
    stdout.put( "Feed Me B: " );
    stdin.get( iDataValue2 );  
    push( iDataValue1 );
    push( iDataValue2 );
    call recursiveSubtraction;
    mov(EAX, DifferenceInt);
    stdout.put("RecursiveSubtraction of A-B = ",DifferenceInt, nl);
    stdout.put("EAX = ",EAX, nl);
    stdout.put("EBX = ",EBX, nl);
    stdout.put("ECX = ",ECX, nl);   
end MainSubtractionFunction;
```

Answer (score 0):

***ENVIRONMENT***

- HLA (High Level Assembler - HLABE back end, POLINK linker)
  Version 2.16 build 4413 (prototype)
- Windows 10

***NOTE***

- The recursive algorithm in this question works for the following cases: `positive - positive`, `positive - negative`, and `negative - positive` but will not work for the case `negative - negative`.

***SOLUTION***

- The problem is after returning from the recursive call to `recursiveSubtraction` the code will always sequentially continue to the `AEqualsZero` label.

```
NeitherEqualZero:
    sub(1, EAX);
    sub(1, EBX);
    push(EAX);
    push(EBX);
    call recursiveSubtraction;
AEqualsZero:
    neg(EBX);
    mov(EBX, EAX);
    jmp ExitSequence;
```

- To solve this problem add an additional `jmp ExitSequence` after the call to `recursiveSubtraction`.

```
NeitherEqualZero:
    sub(1, EAX);
    sub(1, EBX);
    push(EAX);
    push(EBX);
    call recursiveSubtraction;
    jmp ExitSequence;
AEqualsZero:
    neg(EBX);
    mov(EBX, EAX);
    jmp ExitSequence;
```

***EXAMPLE***

```
program MainSubtractionFunction;
#include("stdlib.hhf");

procedure recursiveSubtraction(A: int32; B: int32); @nodisplay; @noframe;
begin recursiveSubtraction;
    pop(EDX); // Return Address
    pop(EBX);           
    pop(EAX);
    push(EDX); // Return Address
    CompareB:
        cmp(EBX, 0);
        je ExitSequence;
    CompareA:
        cmp(EAX, 0);
        je AEqualsZero;
    NeitherEqualZero:
        dec(EAX);
        dec(EBX);
        push(EAX);
        push(EBX);
        call recursiveSubtraction;
        jmp ExitSequence;
    AEqualsZero:
        neg(EBX);
        mov(EBX, EAX);
        jmp ExitSequence;
    BEqualsZero:
        jmp ExitSequence;
    ExitSequence:
        ret();
end recursiveSubtraction;

begin MainSubtractionFunction;
    stdout.put("Feed Me A: ");
    stdin.geti32();
    push(EAX);
    stdout.put("Feed Me B: ");
    stdin.geti32();
    push(EAX);
    call recursiveSubtraction;
    stdout.put("RecursiveSubtraction of A-B = ", (type int32 EAX), nl);  
end MainSubtractionFunction;
```